# How to hide sub-menu from Applications menu remotely?

Tags: gnome

How can I remove the *Games* sub-menu from the *Applications* menu remotely? I don't want to remove it completely, I just don't want to show it in the *Applications* menu. So that I can revert it back if I need it again. I want to remove it from more than 200 ubuntu PCs,  that is why I would prefer a remote method for doing this task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit `/usr/share/desktop-directories/Game.directory` and add a `NoDisplay=true` line.

This will hide the Games category (and all of the games) from the default menu.  Individual users will be able to re-enable the category in `alacarte` if they so choose.

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click on your Application button on the panel, select Edit Menus
2. Click on Applications, it's the very first item on the left side.
3. On the right side, uncheck the Game item.

You are done.

If you want to do this remotely for 200 computers, take a look at

```
/etc/xdg/menus/applications.menu
```

I looked more carefully in the file above, so basically if you remove the section from

```
<!-- Games -->
to
<!-- End Games -->
```

save it in another file, and then you can swap the file remotely.  You can probably accomplish this.

Comment: not really what he's asking, imagine doing this on 200 pc's?

Comment: i think /etc/xdg/menus/applications.menu can edit out the game part, not certain though.

Comment: Note that removing the games section from applications.menu will dump all of your game shortcuts into the "Other" section, which may not be what you were expecting.